# Sqlalchemy can't find schema after switching from MySQl to Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm switching the underlying database from MySQL to Postgres and have come across an issue with schema. I understand schema is a concept that doesn't exist in MySql. I'm lost as in how to proceed.

The PyTest is throwing this error:  `schema "main_db" does not exist`. Although I have created the database like this.

`sudo -u houmie createdb main_db`

[image]

When I login via Dbeaver I can confirm that the schema is showing as `public`. I don't understand what Sqlalchemy is expecting. I suppose I have to define `public` somewhere?

```
self = <sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.psycopg2.PGDialect_psycopg2 object at 0x10d407d60>, cursor = <cursor object at 0x10d17ea90; closed: -1>
statement = '\nCREATE TABLE main_db.account (\n\tid SERIAL NOT NULL, \n\temail VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, \n\tpassword VARCHAR(100) NO...IMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, \n\tis_banned BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, \n\tstrikes INTEGER, \n\tPRIMARY KEY (id)\n)\n\n', parameters = {}
context = <sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.psycopg2.PGExecutionContext_psycopg2 object at 0x10d69d580>

    def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
>       cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
E       sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidSchemaName) schema "main_db" does not exist
E       LINE 2: CREATE TABLE main_db.account (
E                            ^
E
E       [SQL:
E       CREATE TABLE main_db.account (
E           id SERIAL NOT NULL,
E           email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
E           password VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
E           type accounttype NOT NULL,
E           updated_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
E           created_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
E           is_confirmed BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
E           confirmed_on TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
E           is_banned BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
E           strikes INTEGER,
E           PRIMARY KEY (id)
E       )
E
E       ]
E       (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405)

../../.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/envs/v395/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py:608: ProgrammingError
```

The model itself is defined like this:

```
metadata = MetaData(schema="main_db")
AccountTable = sqlalchemy.Table(
    "account",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("email", String(100), index=True, nullable=False, unique=True),
    Column("password", String(100), nullable=False),
    Column("type", Enum(AccountType), nullable=False),
    Column("updated_at", TIMESTAMP(), onupdate=func.now()),
    Column(
        "created_at",
        TIMESTAMP(),
        nullable=False,
        default=func.now(),
        server_default=func.now(),
    ),
    Column(
        "is_confirmed",
        Boolean,
        nullable=False,
        server_default=text("0"),
        default=text("0"),
    ),
    Column("confirmed_on", TIMESTAMP(), nullable=True),
    Column(
        "is_banned",
        Boolean(),
        nullable=False,
        server_default=text("0"),
        default=text("0"),
    ),
    Column("strikes", Integer()),
)
```

Comment: Why are you using a schema? You only created a database, not a schema within the database.

Comment: Read https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/ddl-schemas.html and see if you really need to use anything other than the default schema.

Comment: Thanks. Based on my research when a database is created in Postgresql as I did, it will be automatically assigned to the public schema. I'm still unsure how to solve the issue. Do I have to create a schema separately? `CREATE SCHEMA myschema;` And how do I have to change the SqlAlchemy settings to consider the new schema?

Comment: You already told SQLAlchemy to use `myschema`; you’ll need to create it in PostgreSQL with `CREATE SCHEMA`.

Comment: If you removed the `schema` argument from MetaData (`metadata = MetaData()`) then the default schema for the user is used; on a new database that is going to be `Public`. See the section on the schema search path in the docs I linked you to.

Comment: You're correct. I just figured it out and was about to write about it. `metadata = MetaData()` is the solution. Thank you